# Media folder not being created

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create the media folder that would store all profile pictures, however this folder is not being created.

This is what I have in my urls.py:

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns= urlpatterns+static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

and settings.py:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'django.template.context_processors.media',
            ],
        },
    },
]
...
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

Comment: Have you uploaded a file? Or did that give an error?

Comment: did u do the command : 
python manage.py collectstatic

Comment: @dirkgroten So i'm trying to upload a profile picture along with other profile information, i don't get an error, everything else is updated except for the picture

Comment: @khaledhadjali i had not, it just added an admin folder to static though

Comment: @Emm try to stop the server and run it  one more time . ur setting are right done .

Comment: @khaledhadjali tried again, no media folder still

Comment: You need to create the media folder yourself. MEDIA_ROOT should point to an existing folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django doesn't create the media folder for you. You need to provide a path to a folder that you want to be used as your media folder.

Django docs on  [**`MEDIA_ROOT`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#std:setting-MEDIA_ROOT):

> Absolute filesystem path to the directory that will hold user-uploaded files.

But django can and will create folders inside the media folder if necessary.